# In what kind of stochastic process Ito's lemma is adopted?

Tags: stochastic-processes, itos-lemma

I have been told that Ito's lemma serves as the stochastic calculus counterpart of the chain rule. And yet again my tutor mentioned it is not used for all stochastic processes.

Is this statement true?

If so what are the conditions in which Ito's lemma is used?

Comment: This is a site for professional quants. Concerning this question: Wikipedia is your friend.

Comment: @vonjd Are you sure? "Basically, your question must be one that someone who is

earning a living at this, or
is studying this specifically in graduate school
would confront in the course of their job or studies."

Comment: If your tutor is a tutor of stochastic analysis, then he should teach it as a whole. Basically Ito's lemma is used for processes that can be described as solutions to SDE's (stochastic differential equaions). There is a version for jump processes too.